# VB.NET Regular expression 0-9 and a-z not working?

Tags: regex, string, c-strings

How can i make a regex expression for numbers and letters? whenever i input it only reads the strings in order not randomize. lets say i input 312 <-- it would be invalid identifier because its number variable is not in order. On letters i tried a123456789 so whenver i input a1, a2, a3 it reads as identifier because its in order. and i wanted also to create another variable that will combine numbers and letters.

```
    Dim input As String = txtInput.Text
    Dim symbol As String = "\s*([-+*/=])\s*"
    Dim numbers As String = "123456789" //("[0-9]") <-- doesnt work?
    Dim letters As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" // ("[a-z]")<-also

    Dim substrings() As String = Regex.Split(input, symbol)

    For Each match As String In substrings
        If symbol.Contains(match) Then
            lstOutput.Items.Add(match & " - operator")
        ElseIf numbers.Contains(match) Then
            lstOutput.Items.Add(match & " - number")
        ElseIf letters.Contains(match) Then
            lstOutput.Items.Add(match & " - identifier")
        Else
            lstOutput.Items.Add(match & " - Invalid Identifier")
        End If
    Next
```

Input: c1 + 2c + cad + c1b

expected output:

c1 - identifier

- - operator

2c - invalid identifier // invalid because the 1st character is number

- - operator

cad - identifier

- - operator

c1b -  identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use regex patterns for numbers and identifiers with `Regex.IsMatch`.

*Number pattern*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]*` - 0+ digits
- `\.?` - an optional dot
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string

*Identifier pattern*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z_]` - an ASCII letter or `_`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_]*` - 0+ ASCII letters, digits or `_`
- `$` - end of string.

  Dim input As String = "c1 + 2c + cad + c1b"
  Dim symbol As String = "\s*([-+*/=])\s*"
  Dim numbers As String = "^[0-9]*.?[0-9]+$"
  Dim letters As String = "^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$"

  Dim substrings() As String = Regex.Split(input, symbol)

  For Each match As String In substrings
      If Regex.IsMatch(match, symbol) Then
          Console.WriteLine(match & " - operator")
      ElseIf Regex.IsMatch(match, numbers) Then
          Console.WriteLine(match & " - number")
      ElseIf Regex.IsMatch(match, letters) Then
          Console.WriteLine(match & " - identifier")
      Else
          Console.WriteLine(match & " - Invalid Identifier")
      End If
  Next

See the [VB.NET demo](http://ideone.com/3LbxNK) outputting

```
c1 - identifier
+ - operator
2c - Invalid Identifier
+ - operator
cad - identifier
+ - operator
c1b - identifier
```